# Will a 95 4AFE engine work on Euro 4 gasoline?

Tags: engine, toyota, fuel-system, gasoline

I am hearing news in our country that they might upgrade our fuel from EURO 2 gasoline to EURO 4. I am worried that it might damage the engine on my 95 corolla, which I still plan on keeping for at least a few more years. My car currently has 130,000km and still pretty much runs solid. I am just worried that the fuel upgrade might damage the engine. I am not concerned with the fuel efficiency as I am already expecting it to be less efficient.

Comment: Can you provide a link? As far as I know, EURO 2 and 4 are emissions standards, not fuel types...

Comment: But would the mixture of fuel affect the way the engine would run? or would it make more beneficial to it? https://ph.news.yahoo.com/denr-requires-cleaner-fuel-july-000000014.html

Comment: It clarifies half way through the article, stating "*He clarified that Euro 4 fuel could still be loaded in old vehicles.*" (the "He" being Environment Secretary Ramon Paje). I don't think you'll have an issue.

Comment: I'm just a bit skeptical with what our government officials say, they mostly give statements with no background about the matter, or just sometimes outright lying about it. I'm just making sure he's not saying something that's not a fact. At least I'm informed now that EURO emisssion standards do no directly affect fuel types. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It clarifies half way through the article, stating "He clarified that Euro 4 fuel could still be loaded in old vehicles." (the "He" being Environment Secretary Ramon Paje). I don't think you'll have an issue.